# Ввод логина и пароля C# + Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Есть ресурс - https://adminqa.pnmsoftlabs.com/Default.aspx
если его открыть, то появляется всплывающее окно, в него нужно ввести логин и пароль. Как при запуске теста обеспечить ввод логина и пароля?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

сайт не открылся, но уверен что там была серверная аутентификация ( server authentication )

- Раньше основным решением было введение логина и пароля через адресную строку

  ```
  http://username:password@example.com/yourpage
  ```

  это разновидность [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#URL_encoding), которая была отменена RFC-3986 из-за ее небезопасности и сейчас не очень актуальна. Да и когда была актуальна, то срабатывало далеко не всегда ибо далеко не всюду это было реализовано.
- Другим решением было добавление нужных куки в которых ты уже залогиненый на сайт:

  ```
  driver.manage().addCookie()
  ```
- Или же создание готового профиля браузера в котором ты залогинен и проведении тестов на нем.
- Или использование профилей браузеров с какими-то Auto-Auth плагинами (если первый способ не срабатывал, а нужно использовать разные креденшалы)

---

- Но начиная с Selenium 3.4 добавилась нейтивная поддержка попапа аутентификации:

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
  Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
  alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
  ```